# issue with ostream and << overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

I have this printing line of code:

```
 std::cout << *it << std::endl;
```

now, since 'it' is a complex type I need to write my own '<<' operator.
this is my function:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Node& n ){
    return os << n.key << ':' << n.value;
}
```

I get an error "type ostream could not be resolved"
I've tried adding std:: before "ostream" but that doesn't help. I'm not sure what else I can try.

Comment: Next time you should construct a [testcase](http://sscce.org). This would undoubtedly have solved your problem before you needed to post here at all and, if you still needed to post here, we'd have something concrete to examine.

Answer (score 4):

You need to `#include <ostream>` (`<iostream>` is not be enough if you're using C++03).

If you've done that, *and* used the `std::` qualifying prefix, then there's something you're not telling us or you're compiling the wrong file!

---

```
#include <ostream>   // for std::ostream
#include <iostream>  // for std::cout

struct Node
{
   int key;
   int value;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Node& n) {
    return os << n.key << ':' << n.value;
}

int main()
{
   Node n = {3, 5};
   std::cout << n << '\n';
}

// Output: `3:5`
```

#### [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0baf69937528c66)

Comment: This isn't actually accurate. In C++11 iostream is required to include ostream. If you're not targetting C++11 then I forget exactly what the rules are but wouldn't you need `Node n = { 3, 5 }`?